# Is there legal recourse against revenge defecation?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, common-law, civil-legal-system

## TL;DR

If someone were to maliciously defecate in their roommate's room, perhaps hiding it under their bed or in a drawer, what kind of legal action could their roommate take against them.

## Background

My sister-in-law (we'll call her Anne) has a terrible, horrible roommate (we'll say Jane) that actively makes her life miserable. Thankfully, Anne is moving into a new place in a month, but things are still very bad between them.

Earlier this week, Anne woke up with stomach pains and could tell she had diarrhea. She laid in bed for a while, but eventually got the energy to get up to use the bathroom. Jane has a habit of waiting to hear Anne get up, then rush into the bathroom and monopolize it for an hour+ (she absolutely does it on purpose). Anne has been forced to urinate in the kitchen sink a handful of times because of this. So when this happened on diarrhea morning, Anne laid on the floor trying to wait it out. Jane decided to take her 4th shower in 24 hours (she had also taken one at 4 AM for some reason), and, because the door was still locked, **Anne was forced to poop into the kitchen sink and use the garbage disposal to wash it down.** Afterwards, she and her sisters talked on the phone about how she should have just pooped in Jane's room, perhaps hiding it somewhere. Anne remarked that she may just do that anyway as a parting gift.

If she does poop in Jane's room, is there some sort of legal action Jane could pursue against Anne? How serious would it be? (Anne lives in LA)

Comment: In [this case](https://nypost.com/2017/11/01/roommate-from-hells-sick-sabotage-involved-bloody-tampons-licked-utensils/), a roommate was charged with third-degree criminal mischief and second-degree breach of peace.

Comment: Why not just not do it?